# How to iterate through array of objects in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Trying to iterate array of objects using es6 as it is very new for me

here is my array of objects

```
[j]
0: j
$extCollectionIndex: 0
data: {ID: "b7f7ce8b-1455-41b3-ac26-b54916f6718f", userId: "444441", userName: "cjtest.1", email: "cjtest@gmail.com",  …}
```

need to return or console username

I just tried(map and find )

```
let obj = records.map(obj => {return obj.data});

console.log(obj)//[object,object]
```

can any one help me on this

Comment: can you post the whole array?

Comment: ...obj.data.userName

Comment: What's wrong with `map` ?

Comment: Your question is pretty vague, but I'd assume you need something like
`for (let object of records) { console.log(object.data.username); }`

Comment: `records.map(obj => obj.data.username);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the output

```
let obj = records.map(obj => {return obj.data.username});

console.log(obj)//cjtest.1
```

Thanks you @Weedoze  @gaetanoM

Answer (score 3):

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map) will return a new array. If you return `obj.data` you will have an array of objects.
You need to be more specific about the data you need.

```
let obj = records.map(obj => obj.data.userName );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use your `map` function over `record.data.userName` and not just `record.data`, you can then print it out using `join`. Or use a forEach loop with a `console.log` inside.

Working example :

```js
function foo(){
  const records = [
      {
          "data": {
              "ID": "b7f7ce8b-1455-41b3-ac26-b54916f6718f",
              "userId": "444441",
              "userName": "cjtest.1",
              "email": "cjtest@gmail.com"
          }
      },
      {
          "data": {
              "ID": "b7f7ce8b-1455-41b3-ac26-b54916f6718f",
              "userId": "444441",
              "userName": "srtkjrthrt",
              "email": "cjtest@gmail.com"
          }
      },
      {
          "data": {
              "ID": "b7f7ce8b-1455-41b3-ac26-b54916f6718f",
              "userId": "444441",
              "userName": "srthstrj",
              "email": "cjtest@gmail.com"
          }
      },
      {
          "data": {
              "ID": "b7f7ce8b-1455-41b3-ac26-b54916f6718f",
              "userId": "444441",
              "userName": "cjghj1",
              "email": "cjtest@gmail.com"
          }
      }
  ]
  const userList = records.map(record => record.data.userName)
  console.log(userList.join(', '))
}

foo()
```